# WPF ObservableCollection & InotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: wpf, mvvm, observablecollection, icommand

the model class represents the database. I pull the data from the database in the viewmodel and display it in the datagrid. When I change the corresponding cell in the datagrid, this change is not reflected in the ObservableCollection object. The old value is coming.

> Model

```
namespace ptkym.Models
{
   using ptkym.Helpers;
   public class M_PKY_Rapor_Sablon_Ek_1_Planlar : ObservableObject
   {
      string document_No;       
      public string Document_No
      {
        get { return document_No; }
        set { document_No = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
       }       
       public M_PKY_Rapor_Sablon_Ek_1_Planlar(string document_No)                                              
       {
            this.Document_No = document_No;            
       } 
       }
      }
```

> ViewModel

```
        namespace ptkym.ViewModels
        {
          using ptkym.Helpers;
          using ptkym.Models;
          using System;
          using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
          using System.Data;
          using System.Linq;
          using System.Windows;
          public class ViewModel
          {
          Sql_class sql = new Sql_class();
          public RelayCommand DisplayMessageCommand { get; private set; }

          private ObservableCollection<Model> obsColl;
          public ObservableCollection<Model> OBSCOLL
           {
                get { return obsColl; }
                set { obsColl = value; }
            }

           public ViewModel()
           {
               obsColl = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
               this.Fill_DataGrid();
                DisplayMessageCommand = new RelayCommand(DisplayMessage);
            }
              private void Fill_DataGrid()
              {
                 sql.QueryString = "SELECT * FROM SQL_Table_Name";
                 DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                 dataTable = sql._DataTable();

               foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
               {
                 obsColl.Add(new Model(dr["Dokuman_No"].ToString())                                  
                }
          }
            public void DisplayMessage(object message)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Sablon_Ek_1_Planlar[0].Document_No);
             }
         }
       }
```

> INotifyPropertyChanged imlement

```
      namespace ptkym.Helpers
      {
        using System.ComponentModel;
        using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
        public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
            {
               PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
         }
      }
```

> View

```
        <Window x:Class="ptkym.Views.PKY_Sablon_Ek_1_Planlar"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ptkym.Views"
            xmlns:lokal="clr-namespace:ptkym.ViewModels"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
           Title="PKY_Sablon_Ek_1_Planlar" Height="512.534" Width="1196.049">

        <Window.DataContext>
             <lokal:ViewModel></lokal:ViewModel>
        </Window.DataContext>


         <Grid Margin="0,0,32,0">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="331*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="65*"/>
           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <DataGrid x:Name="grd" CanUserAddRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Sablon_Ek_1_Planlar, 
        Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="369" 
         Margin="79,42,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1053" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <!--DOCUMENT NO-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="NO">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Document_No, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Content="Button" Command="{Binding DisplayMessageCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
      Margin="204,440,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        </Grid>
       </Window>
```

Comment: Do you mean you don't see any updates while you are typing into the TextBox? Then try to set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the Text Binding. Note that `Mode=TwoWay` is the default anyway.

Answer (score -1):

OBSCOLL needs to call OnPropertyChanged(); inside its setter as well.

Then, in your viewmodel constructor change to:

```
OBSCOLL = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
```

Comment: Why that? Is it assigned somewhere else than in the constructor? The property should instead just be read-only.

Comment: thank you very much @clemens. Problem solved.